# C Optimization Methods

Tags: for-loop, optimization, nested

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 #define DATALEN 15
3 #define FILTERTAPS 5
4 double x[DATALEN] = { 128.0, 130.0, 180.0, 140.0, 120.0,
5                       110.0, 107.0, 103.5, 102.0, 90.0,
6                       84.0, 70.0, 30.0, 77.3, 95.7 };
7 const double h[FILTERTAPS]={0.125,-0.25,0.5,-0.25,0.125};
8 double y[DATALEN]; // result;
9 int main(void)
10 {int i,n;
11 for(i=0;i<DATALEN;++i)
12    {y[i]=0;
13    for(n=0;n<FILTERTAPS;++n)
14       if ((i-n)>=0) y[i]+=h[n]*x[i-n];
15    }
16 for(i=0;i<DATALEN;++i) printf("%.2f ",y[i]);
17 return 0;
18 }
```

I've been asked to perform several optimizations on the code above.

I have found little in the way of examples.  The 3 optimizations I am struggling with the most are:

- Removal of the if in the innermost loop (line 14)
- Loop unrolling (line 13)
- Avoidance of all accesses to arrays

How can the if statement be removed from line 14 since n is evaluated within the loop that increments n?

I've done loop unrolling in assembly, but doing so here will depend largely on the result of the first optimization.

As far as avoiding access to arrays, this seems like a pointless optimization, but it has been asked nonetheless.  Doesn't this mean literally coding out each equation possible and printing the result?

i.e. for the case where i=0 and n=0

Assuming y0, y1, .. yn replaces the y array

```
y0=0.125*128;
y1=0.125*130 - 0.25*128;
y2=0.125*180 - 0.25*130 + 0.5*128 ;
printf("%.2f ",y0);
printf("%.2f ",y1);
printf("%.2f ",y2);
```

Comment: i think the goal here is to look at the if statement from another angle. the optimizations 1&2 use the same trick. and you must unroll loop in line 13, but your snippet tries to unroll the one in line 11

Comment: Thanks.  The snippet toward the end was my only solution for removing accesses to arrays.  My first attempt was to simply put the if statement as a condition in the loop, but that really isn't changing the number of branches.  I'm now working on looking at test cases for how I can iterage without using an if statement.